# Initializing a class' function pointer member to the same class' function member

Tags: c++

In the header file of class `Class1`, I've declared a  function pointer `fn_ptr` and a function called `myfunc(int,int)`:

```
class Class1
{
   private: 
      bool (*fn_ptr)(int,int); 

   public:     
      Class1(); //Default Constructor
      bool myfunc(int,int); 
};
```

I want to have `fn_ptr` point to `Class1`'s myfunction defined like so in the class's library file:

```
Class1::Class1()
{
   fn_ptr = myfunc; //Initialization in the 
}

Class1::myfunc(int a, int b)
{
   return a<b; 
}
```

Compiling resulted in an error:
`error: argument of type 'bool (Class1::)(int,int)' does not match 'bool (*)(int,int)'`

Comment: methods have a hidden `this` pointer so regular function pointers can't work the way you want. Read more here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: Also, take a look at [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for a different way to do method pointers

Comment: @user4581301 Your comments are excellent; personally, I feel that lambdas can replace nearly every use of `bind` as a more intuitive alternative.

Answer (score 2):

As user4581301 wrote in the comment, once you have a (non-`static`) member function, it takes a "hidden" pointer to the class's object, so you can't do directly what you tried here - the interfaces just don't match.

Also, there are currently more convenient facilities for function indirection that bare pointers.

Suppose you do the following. First, declare the class like this:

```
#include <functional>                                                                                                                                                                                    



using namespace std;


class Class1
{
private:
    std::function<bool(int, int)> fn;

public:     
    Class1(); //Default Constructor
    bool myfunc(int,int){ return true; }
};
```

Note how the member `fn` is of type [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), which is more convenient and versatile.

Now in the constructor, you can simply initialize it with a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
Class1::Class1() :
    fn([this](int i, int j){return myfunc(i, j);})
{

}
```

It says that for any `i` and `j`, just call `myfunc` (on `this` objet) on these arguments, and return the result.

---

**Full code**

Make sure to build using c++11 settings.

```
#include <functional>                                                                                                                                                                                    



using namespace std;


class Class1
{
private:
    std::function<bool(int, int)> fn;

public:     
    Class1(); //Default Constructor
    bool myfunc(int,int){ return true; }
};


Class1::Class1() :
    fn([this](int i, int j){return myfunc(i, j);})
{

}

int main()
{
    Class1 c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Ami's excellent answer about using `std::function` instead, member function pointers have different syntax, which is why it didn't work for you.

```
bool (Class1::*fn_ptr)(int,int); //note the Class1::

fn_ptr = &Class1::my_func; //the &Class1:: is necessary, forgetting it is a compilation error
```

Calling it is different, too. It needs an instance of the class to be called on.

```
Class1 c;
(c.*fn_ptr)(1, 2); //or (this->*fn_ptr) too
```